# Is "majorily" a word?

Tags: adverbs

For years I have been using "majorily" in a sentence to identify the majority class. For example: "The balloons were majorily red, with a few blue balloons scattered about." or "When it comes to fish; Bears are majorily associated with Salmon". Today, I noticed that this word doesn't seem to appear in any dictionary.

I understand that "majorly" is a word, and many people may misspell it to arrive at "majorily". However, I was under the impression that they were two distinct words with different uses and pronunciations. As far as I can tell, there is no pronunciation of "majorly" that sounds like how I would pronounce "majorily" (muh-jawr-i-lee).

I cannot say where I picked up the word, only that I don't seem to be the only person who uses it. Could it be a misuse of "majority"? I'm not entirely sure if majority could be used in the same way.

Comment: if you are looking for a simple but correct alternative, try "mostly". a less simple but also correct alternative is "predominantly". "majority" is a noun so it cannot be used as an adverb.

Comment: Pretty sure you made that one up.

Comment: I'd say even ***majorly*** is a pretty "slangy" usage, so it wouldn't surprise me if lots of dictionaries don't include it. And ***?majorily*** is presumably some kind of mistake by OP, which for some reason no-one has ever pointed out before.

Comment: If the balloons where *predominantly* red, I would take that to mean that the majority of balloons were red in color; if they were *mostly* red, I would understand that most of the surface of each balloon was red.

Comment: Thanks semantax, I had forgotten about predominantly. As Malvolio said, I think predominantly suggests that the majority of the balloons were red. Mostly might be too ambiguous, depending on the situation.

Comment: I would say that grizzly bears are *primarily* associated with salmon.

Comment: As my Dad would often say..."look it up".  What did you find when you looked it up in the dictionary or Googled it?  Please bring your research to the question.

Comment: No online dictionary in *onelook.com* lists *majorily*. Not definitive, but a fair indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Majorily* is not a standard English word.  It might be slang, or it might be recently coined.

For your first example, a better construction is "Most of the balloons were red, with a few blue balloons scattered about." If you were trying to suggest that the balloons were not solid colors, you would need a different construction.

Your second example is colloquial to the point of absurdity. Bears do not associate with salmon. Bears prey upon salmon; bears eat salmon.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes, the second example was fairly absurd. Sorry about that.

I think predominantly is the best alternative, as suggested in one of the other comments.

Comment: The second example is not particularly absurd.  To say that bears are associated with salmon is not to imply that the bears associate with the salmon.  It means that *people* associate the bears with salmon, as one might associate a moonlit evening with romance.  The relevant sense of "to associate" here is "to connect in the mind or imagination."